# Is it possible automatically compile depended project into jar in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, ear, rtc

For example I have a regular **Java** project and multiple **EAR** projects JSF + EJB inside EAR. Each EAR project has as a dependency, my Java project, for example it might be a library of composite JSF components.

Is it possible to define that when I exporting an **EAR** project it will compile depended **Java** project into **jar** and put it as a library inside EAR\libs?

Same thing regarding committing project via **RTC**, now I need manually build jar and add it to my EAR project, is it possible to do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

RTC wouldn't provide any additional compilation feature compared to the platform (Eclipse) it is installed on.

It does provide however RTC Builds, and you could use that task scheduler to, on demand, trigger the compilation of the Java project and its import into the `ear/libs`.

That supposes first that you can do those tasks in a script (using any scripting technique you want: ant, maven shell, bash, anything).
Then you can define a build definition using that script.